# C# double value from c# dll lose decimal positions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll, double

this is really my first time asking here, but I'm facing a problem which I'm sure of I'm missing something simple.

I wrote a C# class library with a function that returns a List>. The function itself works fine if used from a console application that I created to test the DLL.
The ending part of the function is:

```
  /* Sorto i risultati in base al ranking */
        List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> SortedList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>(matchIndexList_rank);

        SortedList.Sort(delegate(KeyValuePair<string, double> firstPair,
            KeyValuePair<string, double> secondPair)
            {
                return (-1) * firstPair.Value.CompareTo(secondPair.Value);
            }
        );

        stopWatch.Stop();

        response.success = true;
        response.executionTime = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        response.resultListKVPStrDoub = SortedList;

        return response;
```

Here for example the double part of the first value in the list is 15.5796761265999 (sorry cannot include pictures yet!)

The problem rises if I include the DLL in a ASP.NET MVC Application that uses the function. In this case the double part of the List> is returned without the decimal part.

The corresponding value to the one presented above is returned as 155796761265999.0

Here is a little bit of code where i get the wrong value returned:

```
        searchEngine.Core.search search = new searchEngine.Core.search(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/index_" + oIdentity.comapanyId.ToString()));
        searchEngine.Core.genericResponse response = search.doSearch(searchStr);

        double maxScore = response.resultListKVPStrDoub.Count > 0 ? response.resultListKVPStrDoub[0].Value : 1;
```

In example maxScore get the 155796761265999.0 value, but also every other value in the List suffers the same problem.

If I inspect the variables from both sides Visual Studio 2013 states that the type is indeed a double.

Both projects are developed on the same machine which also is my test environment. I use .Net Framework 4.0 on both projects and all build parameters seems to be equal on both projects.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but just can't get.
I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Lorenzo

**Hi, problem solved !** (sorry but I can't yet answer by own question before 8 hours from posting)

Thanks to Radu Pascal that put me on the right way: normally I always add a class library to a solution to debug it, but in this case I had it developed for another project and it was working fine so I ignored the obviuos.

Thanks to Marc Gravell, he spotted the problem: even if I forgot it at the base of my search engine there is a file based index. There is where i reed my values from text and there is where I do the reading wrong.

The real mystery is that the same DLL used in the console application used for testing and even on another ASP.NET MVC on the same machine works fine. I solved using double.parse instead of Convert.ToDouble and imposing an invariant culture.

```
idfDict[idItem] = double.Parse(s.Split('|')[1], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Thanks to all!
Lorenzo

Comment: Is the value ever written to (say) a string, and parsed back?

Comment: No ! Sadly it is just passed directly from the DLL.

Comment: Why can't you debug the DLL and see how your method behaves when running the ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: This seems like a localization issue.  Could one of the two be using . as a thousands separator?  Edit:  I just realized that Marc may have been alluding to this.

Comment: What is happening with your "response"?  Is it getting serialized?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, problem solved !**

Thanks to Radu Pascal that put me on the right way: normally I always add a class library to a solution to debug it, but in this case I had it developed for another project and it was working fine so I ignored the obviuos.

Thanks to Marc Gravell, he spotted the problem: even if I forgot it at the base of my search engine there is a file based index. There is where i reed my values from text and there is where I do the reading wrong.

The real mystery is that the same DLL used in the console application used for testing and even on another ASP.NET MVC on the same machine works fine. I solved using double.parse instead of Convert.ToDouble and imposing an invariant culture.

```
idfDict[idItem] = double.Parse(s.Split('|')[1], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Thanks to all!
Lorenzo